# Predict ignores newdata argument in feglm estimation

Tags: r, glm, predict

After estimating my model

```
train_data <- df_est_hdfe[idx,]
test_data <- df_est_hdfe[-idx,]

est <- c("NATURAL", "GDPsim", "cap_lab_sim", "cap_lab_sim_sq", "cont")
form <- formula(paste0("rta ~ ",paste(est, collapse = " + "), "| exp_ind + imp_ind"))

train_data <- as.data.frame(train_data)

probithdfe <- feglm(form, data = train_data[,c("rta", est, "exp_ind", "imp_ind")], family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

I would like to use it to predict the output given some new data

```
pred_LM <- predict(probithdfe, newdata = test_data[,c(est, "exp_ind", "imp_ind")], type = "response")
```

However, I can't get my new data into the predict function as

```
dim(test_data)
[1] 5910   13
```

while

```
length(pred_LM)
[1] 11546
```

which is the size of the training data. How can I apply my estimated model to new data? I assume this might be specific to the feglm specification of the `alpaca` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using the `fixest` package, which yields almost identical estimates but lets me pass new data into the `predict` function. The code is identical to the one displayed above as both packages (`fixest` and `alpaca`) use the same `feglm` command for the estimation.